# Java copy files matching pattern from many folders to another folder

Tags: java, nio

Please take a look at the code I have so far and if possible explain what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to learn.

I made a little program to search for a type of file in a directory and all its sub-directories and copy them into another folder.

**Code**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

public class FandFandLoop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final File folder = new File("C:/Users/ina/src");

        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

        search(".*\\.txt", folder, result);

        File to = new File("C:/Users/ina/dest");

        for (String s : result) {
            System.out.println(s);
            File from = new File(s);
            try {
                copyDir(from.toPath(), to.toPath());
                System.out.println("done");
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public static void copyDir(Path src, Path dest) throws IOException {
        Files.walk(src)
                .forEach(source -> {
                    try {
                        Files.copy(source, dest.resolve(src.relativize(source)),
                                        StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
    }

    public static void search(final String pattern, final File folder, List<String> result) {
        for (final File f : folder.listFiles()) {

            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                search(pattern, f, result);
            }

            if (f.isFile()) {
                if (f.getName().matches(pattern)) {
                    result.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

It works, but what it actually does is to take my `.txt` files and write them into another file named `dest` without extension.

And at some point, it deletes the folder `dest`.

The deletion happens because of `StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING`, if I understand this, but what I would have liked to obtain was that if several files had the same name then only one copy of it should be kept.

Comment: The question title is misleading. Could you rephrase it, for example to "Copy all files matching pattern to folder" or similar (if that is your intention)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to call `Files.walk` on the matched source files.

You can improve this code by switching completely to using `java.nio.file.Path` and not mixing string paths and `File` objects. Additionally instead of calling `File.listFiles()` recursively you can use [`Files.walk`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk(java.nio.file.Path,int,java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...)) or even better [`Files.find`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#find(java.nio.file.Path,int,java.util.function.BiPredicate,java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...)).

So you could instead use the following:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UncheckedIOException;
import java.nio.file.CopyOption;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.PathMatcher;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.function.BiPredicate;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class CopyFiles {
    public static void copyFiles(Path src, Path dest, PathMatcher matcher, CopyOption... copyOptions) throws IOException {
        // Argument validation
        if (!Files.isDirectory(src)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Source '" + src + "' is not a directory");
        }
        if (!Files.isDirectory(dest)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Destination '" + dest + "' is not a directory");
        }
        Objects.requireNonNull(matcher);
        Objects.requireNonNull(copyOptions);

        BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes> filter = (path, attributes) -> attributes.isRegularFile() && matcher.matches(path);

        // Use try-with-resources to close stream as soon as it is not longer needed
        try (Stream<Path> files = Files.find(src, Integer.MAX_VALUE, filter)) {
            files.forEach(file -> {
                Path destFile = dest.resolve(src.relativize(file));
                try {
                    copyFile(file, destFile, copyOptions);
                }
                // Stream methods do not allow checked exceptions, have to wrap it
                catch (IOException ioException) {
                    throw new UncheckedIOException(ioException);
                }
            });
        }
        // Wrap UncheckedIOException; cannot unwrap it to get actual IOException 
        // because then information about the location where the exception was wrapped 
        // will get lost, see Files.find doc
        catch (UncheckedIOException uncheckedIoException) {
            throw new IOException(uncheckedIoException);
        }
    }

    private static void copyFile(Path srcFile, Path destFile, CopyOption... copyOptions) throws IOException {
        Path destParent = destFile.getParent();

        // Parent might be null if dest is empty path
        if (destParent != null) {
            // Create parent directories before copying file
            Files.createDirectories(destParent);
        }

        Files.copy(srcFile, destFile, copyOptions);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path srcDir = Paths.get("path/to/src");
        Path destDir = Paths.get("path/to/dest");
        // Could also use FileSystem.getPathMatcher
        PathMatcher matcher = file -> file.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".txt");
        copyFiles(srcDir, destDir, matcher);
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `filter` you should be using `attributes.isRegularFile()`, otherwise the `BasicFileAttributes` is read twice—once to give the filter a value, another time when calling `Files#isRegularFile`.

Comment: Yes, that was spaghetti code :( Thank you for the comments, it helps. It does almost exactly what I had in mind, but not quite - I would have wanted to copy the files in the `dest` folder and this code copies the files _and_ recreates their respective directories in `dest`. Which I have to admit is pretty awesome.  But not 100% what I wanted to achieve. Anyway please don't tell me the answer yet. I'd like to figure it out by myself. Thank you again!